# Navigation Drawer with animated design in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I was wondering how can I get a navigation drawer like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this library is exactly what you are looking for: [AndroidResideMenu](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu)

[image]

Have a look at the examples.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. This is exactly what I wanted. :)